# Python: How do I return strings in def's that contain if/else funtions

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, if-statement

So, I've been working on this problem for a while now and have done research and double checked my code but I can't figure out whats wrong.

The problem I'm having is when I try to print OR return a string it isn't doing anything. If I take the strings out separately they work fine. Here's part of my code. (I have two sections of code like this and neither are doing anything the first has if and elif and the second if and else)

```
speed=int(input("Expected average speed in MPH?"))

def response(speed):

    if speed > 80:


        return "Your travelling dangerously fast, as well as breaking the law. Slow down."


    elif speed < 60:


        return "Your going slow. Please speed up to not be a hinderance to other traffic."
```

This part of my code isn't showing up in the final result. I can't think of what I could be doing wrong. Whereas if I just did this it works fine.

```
enter=int(input("Enter I-15 at what mile marker?"))

exit=int(input("Exit I-15 at what mile marker?"))

def milestotravel(exit, enter):
    return abs(exit-enter)

print ("You will travel: "+str(milestotravel(exit, enter))+" miles.")
```

My entire code so far: (Still working on some of it)

```
enter=int(input("Enter I-15 at what mile marker?"))

exit=int(input("Exit I-15 at what mile marker?"))

goal=float(input("How many hours from now do you want to arrive?"))

speed=int(input("Expected average speed in MPH?"))


def milestotravel(exit, enter):
    return abs(exit-enter)

def traveltime(speed, goal):
    return goal/speed

def response(speed):

    if speed > 80:

        print "Your travelling dangerously fast, as well as breaking the law. Slow down."

    elif speed < 60:
        print "Your going slow. Please speed up to not be a hinderance to other traffic."


print ("You will travel: "+str(milestotravel(exit, enter))+" miles.")


def response2(traveltime, goal, speed):

    if traveltime(speed, goal) > goal:
        print "You will be "+str(traveltime(speed, goal)-goal)+" hours late."

   else:
        print "Leave in the next "+str(traveltime(speed, goal))+" hours to be on time."
```

Comment: hi, you're not calling response(speed) at all, there's no reason for it to print those messages :)

Comment: Where do you _call_ the `response` function? In other words, where do you do `speed=...; response(speed)`?

Comment: I've tried return and print. I changed it back to return just now. I'll post the rest of the code. Also thank you guess so much for helping! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you actually *calling* your function anywhere? It doesn't look like you are. You've defined it (the def code block), but to actually *do* something with it, you have to call it.

Place this in your file (after your def code block):

```
response(speed)
```

Then run your file. Defining a function (def etc...) will not run the function, it will just make it available to you to run later by calling it (just like you call print by saying print('some text')

Also, based on your edit, since you are now returning the strings, you need to add the following to your file (instead of what I wrote above):

```
print(response(speed))
```

Comment: Thank you! :D It worked! I didn't realize I needed to print it outside of the def